# Coloured image warping in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let's say we have a source image on which we want to do some deformations: To relocate the source image pixels into new deformed positions, I use the [griddata](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) function for x and y values separately, which interpolates all the points in the image according to given reference points. I then calculate where each pixels should be remapped on the basis of the griddata outputs.

The colour information, however, is lost during the process. So the output image is in gray scale.

How do I operate with griddata function without losing the colour information?

My question is related to coloured image warping.

Comment: You can do the remapping on each of the three channels, if you have an RGB image, no?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Post some code to get a better feeling of your problem. I'll take a shot in the dark and respond by noting that in matlab, colored images are mxnx3 matrices. Thus the R channel is A(:,:,1), the G channel A(:,:,2) and the B A(:,:,3). Moving from grayscale to color, you'll have to take each color channel matrix separately  and perform your transform (as if on gray), and then combine the three images to a new one (trivially by filling each plane of your new matrix/image with its respective transformed one).

Comment: I actually solved my problem. It was just a matter of treating and reshaping each color channels separately as you guys suggested. Many thanks!

Comment: If you solved the problem please write up a solution and accept it

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the question from remaining open I will quote the comments that led to the solution:

> You can do the remapping on each of the three channels, if you have an
>   RGB image, no?

-

> noting that in matlab, colored images are mxnx3 matrices. Thus the R
>   channel is A(:,:,1), the G channel A(:,:,2) and the B A(:,:,3). Moving
>   from grayscale to color, you'll have to take each color channel matrix
>   separately and perform your transform (as if on gray), and then
>   combine the three images to a new one (trivially by filling each plane
>   of your new matrix/image with its respective transformed one)

-

> I actually solved my problem. It was just a matter of treating and
>   reshaping each color channels separately